# Can't return the last result of recursion function

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, recursion

- I'm trying to loop through the following object

```
var videoElements =  {
    name: "div",
    attr: {
        id: "video-container"
    },
    children: [
        {
            name: "div",
            attr: {
                class: "video-overlay"
            },
            children: [
                {
                    name: "div",
                    attr: {
                        class: "video-top"
                    },
                    children: [
                        {
                            name: "div",
                            attr: {
                                 class: "video-settings"
                            },
                            children: [
                                {
                                    name: "i",
                                    attr: {
                                        class: "fas fa-cog"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    name: "div",
                    attr: {
                        class: "video-middle"
                    },
                    children: [
                        {
                            name: "div",
                            attr: {
                                class: "video-play-btn"
                            },
                            children: [
                                {
                                    name: "i",
                                    attr: {
                                        class: "fas fa-play"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    name: "div",
                    attr: {
                        class: "video-bottom"
                    },
                    children: [
                        {
                            name: "div",
                            attr: {
                                class: "video-bottom-btns"
                            },
                            children: [
                                {
                                    name: "div",
                                    attr: {
                                        class: "video-screen-btn"
                                    },
                                    children: [
                                        {
                                            name: "i",
                                            attr: {
                                                class: "fas fa-expand"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    name: "div",
                                    attr: {
                                        class: "video-volume-btn"
                                    },
                                    children: [
                                        {
                                            name: "i",
                                            attr: {
                                                class: "fas fa-volume-up"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    name: "div",
                                    attr: {
                                        class: "video-download-btn"
                                    },
                                    children: [
                                        {
                                            name: "i",
                                            attr: {
                                                class: "fas fa-arrow-down"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            name: "div",
                            attr: {
                                class: "video-seek"
                            },
                            children: [
                                {
                                    name: "div",
                                    attr: {
                                        class: "video-buffer"
                                    },
                                    children: [
                                        {
                                            name: "div",
                                            attr: {
                                                class: "video-seekable"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: 'div',
            attr: {
                class: 'loading-overlay'
            },
            children: [
                {
                    name: 'div',
                    attr: {
                        class: 'loader'
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

- i used a recursion function to get html elements from above object

> Here's my function

```
function recursion(obj, elem, parentElem) {
    var loopObj = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (obj.constructor === Object) {
                for(i in obj) {
                    if (i === 'name') {
                        parentElem = document.createElement(obj.name)
                    }
                    if (i === 'attr') {
                        for(q in obj.attr) {
                            parentElem.setAttribute(q, obj.attr[q])
                        }
                    }
                    if (i === 'children') {
                        for(r = 0; r < obj[i].length; r++) {
                            if (obj[i][r].name) {
                                var child =document.createElement(obj[i][r].name)
                            }
                            if (obj[i][r].attr) {
                                for(w in obj[i][r].attr) {
                                    child.setAttribute(w, obj[i][r].attr[w])
                                }
                                parentElem.append(child)
                            }
                            if (obj[i][r].children) {
                                recursion(obj[i][r].children, child, parentElem)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else if (obj.constructor === Array) {
                for(i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                    if (obj[i].name) {
                        var child = document.createElement(obj[i].name)
                    }
                    if (obj[i].attr) {
                        for(w in obj[i].attr) {
                            child.setAttribute(w, obj[i].attr[w])
                        }
                    }
                    elem.append(child);
                    if (obj[i].children) {
                        recursion(obj[i].children, child, parentElem)
                    }
                }
                //stop the function here
                return
            }
            if(parentElem) resolve(parentElem)
        })
    })
    loopObj.then(function(htmElem) {
        console.log(htmElem);
        return htmElem;
    })
}
var elements = recursion(videoElements);
console.log(elements);
```

- The problem is when i'm looking for the result in the console i found the element normally but i can't return it because i already calling the function many times so when i'm trying to write `console.log(elements)` it's give me undefined i was thinking to use `Promise.all` but i haven't idea how can i get array of this function so i need someone to help me to get the last result normally when calling the function

## Edited

> Expected Result

```
<div id="video-container">
  <div class="video-overlay">
    <div class="video-top">
      <div class="video-settings">
        <i class="fas fa-cog"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="video-middle">
      <div class="video-play-btn">
        <i class="fas fa-play"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="video-bottom">
      <div class="video-bottom-btns">
        <div class="video-screen-btn">
            <i class="fas fa-expand"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="video-volume-btn">
            <i class="fas fa-volume-up"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="video-download-btn">
            <i class="fas fa-arrow-down"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="video-seek">
        <div class="video-buffer">
          <div class="video-seekable"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="loading-overlay">
    <div class="loader"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what about first building a data structure that holds your data in a "easier" way, and then write an algorithm to manipulate that data structure?

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: What is `recuration`? You almost never `resolve` anything.

Comment: sorry i changed the function name when post the question - i forget to edit the name correctly - anyway i edited it you can try now

Comment: your "recusrsion" function definitely does not return anything - also, every time you call `recursion` it creates a Promise, which only resolves half the time - you'll end up with a ton of unresolved Promises. You also call recursion initially with only one argument, and nowhere in your code can I see a test to see if the other arguments are given, therefore `elem.append` would fail, and `parentElem` could be undefined when you `parentElem.setAttribute` ... and lastly, why is your code using Promises and setTimeout?

Comment: can you stop this and just help me how can i return the last result then show me the mistakes please

Comment: Stop what? telling you where you've gone wrong? please indicate your expected result. You can't return the last result, because your code is fundamentally flawed - you'd need a complete rewrite before you can return anything

Comment: ok i don't said that my code haven't any mistakes i just said i need someone help me solve it and return the value i don't know how you are understand my comment but anyway i edited the post and added the expected result

Comment: i hope that you can help me now or guide me to another function do the same and don't talking about the shit of the code

Comment: @JS_INF: I saw the question, wrote a six-line answer (without generating indentation -- which would add to it), came back to write it up and saw this thread of comments and decided that your attitude meant I didn't want to post it.  StackOverflow is a community.  You need to recognize what it's for.  Jaromanda was trying to help.  S/he doesn't have any requirement to fix your code for you.  Instead s/he offered helpful advice to help you fix it yourself.  That's what SO if about.  Please don't treat it as a code-writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope the below code will work as your expectation.

```
    name: "div",
    attr: {
        id: "video-container"
    },
    children: [
        {
            name: "div",
            attr: {
                class: "video-overlay"
            },
            children: [
                {
                    name: "div",
                    attr: {
                        class: "video-top"
                    },
                    children: [
                        {
                            name: "div",
                            attr: {
                                class: "video-settings"
                            },
                            children: [
                                {
                                    name: "i",
                                    attr: {
                                        class: "fas fa-cog"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    name: "div",
                    attr: {
                        class: "video-middle"
                    },
                    children: [
                        {
                            name: "div",
                            attr: {
                                class: "video-play-btn"
                            },
                            children: [
                                {
                                    name: "i",
                                    attr: {
                                        class: "fas fa-play"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    name: "div",
                    attr: {
                        class: "video-bottom"
                    },
                    children: [
                        {
                            name: "div",
                            attr: {
                                class: "video-bottom-btns"
                            },
                            children: [
                                {
                                    name: "div",
                                    attr: {
                                        class: "video-screen-btn"
                                    },
                                    children: [
                                        {
                                            name: "i",
                                            attr: {
                                                class: "fas fa-expand"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    name: "div",
                                    attr: {
                                        class: "video-volume-btn"
                                    },
                                    children: [
                                        {
                                            name: "i",
                                            attr: {
                                                class: "fas fa-volume-up"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    name: "div",
                                    attr: {
                                        class: "video-download-btn"
                                    },
                                    children: [
                                        {
                                            name: "i",
                                            attr: {
                                                class: "fas fa-arrow-down"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            name: "div",
                            attr: {
                                class: "video-seek"
                            },
                            children: [
                                {
                                    name: "div",
                                    attr: {
                                        class: "video-buffer"
                                    },
                                    children: [
                                        {
                                            name: "div",
                                            attr: {
                                                class: "video-seekable"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: 'div',
            attr: {
                class: 'loading-overlay'
            },
            children: [
                {
                    name: 'div',
                    attr: {
                        class: 'loader'
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}


function recursion(obj, elem, parentElem) {
    if (obj.constructor === Object) {
        for (i in obj) {
            if (i === 'name') {
                parentElem = document.createElement(obj.name)
            }
            if (i === 'attr') {
                for (q in obj.attr) {
                    parentElem.setAttribute(q, obj.attr[q])
                }
            }
            if (i === 'children') {
                var i = 'children'
                for (r = 0; r < obj[i].length; r++) {
                    if (obj[i][r].name) {
                        var child = document.createElement(obj[i][r].name)
                    }
                    if (obj[i][r].attr) {
                        for (w in obj[i][r].attr) {
                            child.setAttribute(w, obj[i][r].attr[w])
                        }
                        parentElem.append(child)
                    }
                    if (obj[i][r].children) {
                        recursion(obj[i][r].children, child, parentElem)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else if (obj.constructor === Array) {
        for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
            if (obj[i].name) {
                var child = document.createElement(obj[i].name)
            }
            if (obj[i].attr) {
                for (w in obj[i].attr) {
                    child.setAttribute(w, obj[i].attr[w])
                }
            }
            elem.append(child);
            if (obj[i].children) {
                recursion(obj[i].children, child, parentElem)
            }
        }
        //stop the function here
        return
    }
    if (parentElem) return (parentElem)
}
var elements = recursion(videoElements);
console.log(elements);
```